# Why does reserving capacity in a gvector in Racket make performance worse?

Tags: performance, vector, profiling, racket

Using the following simple benchmark in Racket 6.6:

```
#lang racket
(require data/gvector)
(define (run)
  ;; this should have to periodically resize in order to incorporate new data
  ;; and thus should be slower
  (time (define v (make-gvector)) (for ((i (range 1000000))) (gvector-add! v i)) )
  (collect-garbage 'major)
  ;; this should never have to resize and thus should be faster
  ;; ... but consistently benchmarks slower?!
  (time (define v (make-gvector #:capacity 1000000)) (for ((i (range 1000000))) (gvector-add! v i)) )
  )

(run)
```

The version that properly reserves capacity **does worse consistently**. Why? This is certainly not the result that I would expect, and is inconsistent with what you would see in C++ (std::vector) or Java (ArrayList). Am I somehow benchmarking incorrectly?

Example output:

```
cpu time: 232 real time: 230 gc time: 104
cpu time: 228 real time: 230 gc time: 120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One benchmarking comment: use `in-range` instead of `range` in your microbenchmarks; otherwise you're including the cost of constructing a million-element list in your measurements.

I added some extra loops to your microbenchmark to make it do more work (and I fixed the `range` issue). Here are some of the results:

Using `#:capacity` for **large capacities** is slower.

```
== 5 iterations of 1e7 sized gvector, measured 3 times each way
with #:capacity
cpu time: 9174 real time: 9169 gc time: 4769
cpu time: 9109 real time: 9108 gc time: 4683
cpu time: 9094 real time: 9091 gc time: 4670
without
cpu time: 7917 real time: 7912 gc time: 3243
cpu time: 7703 real time: 7697 gc time: 3107
cpu time: 7732 real time: 7727 gc time: 3115
```

Using `#:capacity` for **small capacities** is faster.

```
== 20 iterations of 1e6 sized gvector, measured three times each way
with #:capacity
cpu time: 2167 real time: 2168 gc time: 408
cpu time: 2152 real time: 2152 gc time: 385
cpu time: 2112 real time: 2111 gc time: 373
without
cpu time: 2310 real time: 2308 gc time: 473
cpu time: 2316 real time: 2315 gc time: 480
cpu time: 2335 real time: 2334 gc time: 488
```

My hypothesis: it's GC overhead. When the backing vector is mutated, Racket's generational GC remembers the vector so it can scan it in the next minor collection. When the backing vector is very big, scanning the whole vector on every minor GC outweighs the cost of reallocation and copying. The overhead wouldn't occur with a GC with a finer remembered-set granularity (but... tradeoffs).

BTW, looking over the gvector code I found a couple opportunities for improvement. They don't change the big picture, though.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious about the context for writing the growable vectors module, e.g. was there a specific use case?

Comment: @benrudgers, I can't remember for sure. I may have used it in an early version of the macro stepper. It looks like it's currently used in the rackunit gui, where you might not know how many test cases a suite has before you finish running it. It's not a very Rackety data structure.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that context makes sense.

Comment: Is it possible the reserve is zero initializing the memory that it allocates? Because that would hugely increase the cost of large allocations.

Comment: @JosephGarvin, all allocations in Racket initialize the memory. That's not the reason that `#:capacity` is sometimes slower, because it does less allocation than the other version. I'm fairly sure the GC explanation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the vector size with a factor 10 I get the following in DrRacket
(with all debugging turned off):

```
cpu time: 5245 real time: 5605 gc time: 3607
cpu time: 4851 real time: 5136 gc time: 3231
```

Note: If there is garbage left over from the first benchmark it can affect the next one. Therefore use collect-garbage (three times) before using time again.

Also... don't make benchmarks in DrRacket as I did - use the command line.

Comment: why three times? even doing it three times the performance is still consistently worse. also I still see worse performance even with the extra factor of 10, and I am using the commandline

Comment: Due to the way the garbage collector works, once isn't enough. I guess someone has observed that twice isn't enough either because thrice is what's usually recommended.

Comment: when you do it three times do you pass in 'major every time or do you pass in different things?

Comment: I usually just use collect-garbage without any arguments. Maybe 'major was added because using collect-garbage looks silly?